# If EP=EPR is discovered to be equal then would this allow a basis for FTL communication?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, faster-than-light

If EP=EPR is discovered to be equal then would this allow a basis for FTL communication as microscopic wormholes of Planck length act as a bridge for entangled particles. This would only hold true if microscopic wormholes are observed or larger wormholes? Although the mathematics in general seems complete to date.

Comment: Do you mean ER=EPR? If so, it seems unlikely: it's already established that entanglement cannot be used to send information. And, like any FTL communication method, there would still be the problem of causality violation if it worked ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone )